# Fragment UX choice and genericity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I find myself switching between a lot of `Fragment`s in my card game app.

When my user creates a deck he goes through the following fragments:

**Deck List Fragment** (Click on 'New Deck') -> **Class Selection Fragment** (Mage, Warrior etc.) -> **Name Selection Fragment** -> Back to **Deck List Fragment** with our new deck listed.

I do this in order to have a smooth deck creation process but here are my two questions:

1) Is it recommended to use more `Fragment`s than required if it makes the UX better and smoother?

2) Note that I do the following in order to switch `Fragment`:

```
Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

// Set argument(s) - Not all fragments set arguments
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("deckName", deckName);
fragment.setArguments(args);

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Instead of having similar methods from one `Fragment` to the other, I wish to create a generic method that takes a variable amount of parameters and the type of `Fragment` to create and switches to said `Fragment`.

But I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Please excuse this lengthy post, and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my code :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
    }


         public void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .commit();
            }

            public void addFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
                final Fragment hideFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .hide(hideFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(hideFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .commit();
            }
    }
```

Call above methods in Fragment :

```
   final HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("KEY","VALUE");
    homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addFragment(homeFragment);
```

Comment: We could even make the parameter adding generic with a `String... params` parameter to your method, right?
Thank you for your answer anyways